# Return não funciona

Tags: php

O return do método `registrarProduto()` só esta retornando `false`, ele sempre entra no `else` do `if` da pagina produtos.php. Mesmo ele cadastrando o produto tudo certinho no banco ele mostra apenas: **Falha ao cadastrar produto !**.

produtos.php

```
<?php
require 'classes/produtos.class.php';

$p = new Produtos();

    if(empty($_SESSION['pLogin'])) {
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">alert("Lammer não passa daqui 
KKKKKKK!");</script>    
            <script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="index.php";
</script>   
        <?php
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['produto']) && !empty($_POST['produto'])) {

        $produto = addslashes($_POST['produto']);
        $quantidade = addslashes($_POST['quantidade']);

        $p->setProduto($produto);
        $p->setQuantidade($quantidade);
        $p->cadastrarProduto();

        if($p->cadastrarProduto()) {
            echo "Produto cadastrado com sucesso !";
        } else {
            echo "Falha ao cadastrar produto !";
        }
    }

?>
<br/>
<div align="center" class="produtos">
    <h3>CADASTRAR PRODUTOS | AssCTF</h3>
        <form method="post">
            Produto<br/>
            <input type="text" name="produto" /><br/><br/>

            Quantidades<br/>
            <input type="number" name="quantidade" /><br/><br/>

            <input type="submit" name="Cadastrar Produto" />
        </form>
</div>
<table align="center" width="400" border="1">
    <th>Produtos</th>
    <th>Quantidade</th>
<?php
$result = $p->selecionarProduto();
foreach ($result as $item) {
    ?>
    <tr align="center">
        <td><?php echo $item['produto']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item['quantidade']; ?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php
}
?>
</table>
```

produtos.class.php

```
<?php
session_start();

class Produtos {

    private $db;
    private $produto;
    private $quantidade;

    public function __construct() {

        try {

            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=projeto_oo;host=localhost", 
"root", "");

        } catch(PDOException $e) {

            echo "FALHA: ".$e->getMessage();

        }
    }

    public function getProduto() {
        return $this->produto;
    }

    public function setProduto($value) {
        $this->produto = $value;
   }

   public function getQuantidade() {
        return $this->quantidade;
   }

   public function setQuantidade($value) {
        $this->quantidade = $value;
   }

   public function cadastrarProduto() {

        $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE produto = 
:produto");
        $sql->bindValue(":produto", $this->produto);
        $sql->execute();

            if($sql->rowCount() == 0 ) {
                $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO produtos SET produto 
= :produto, quantidade = :quantidade");
                $sql->bindValue(":produto", $this->produto);
                $sql->bindValue(":quantidade", $this->quantidade);
                $sql->execute();

               return true;
            } 
        return false;
    }

    public function selecionarProduto() {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos");
        $sql->execute(); 

        $array = array();

        if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {

            $array = $sql->fetchAll();

        }   
       return $array;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remova essa linha

```
$p->cadastrarProduto();
```

Que está antes desse if

```
if($p->cadastrarProduto()) {
```

Quando você coloca a função como condição no if, ela é executada. Então você está executando duas vezes seguidas a mesma função. Teste e deixe nos comentários.

Comment: Opa, era isso mesmo amigo ! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Beleza, qualquer coisa estamos aí.